# Calling repository.findOne two times in row flushes Hibernate and triggers @PreUpdate listener?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Due to a small implementation error, I have encountered a strange Hibernate behavior, and I could use an explanation as to why it happens.

In my `@Transactional` public method, I have an entity:

`Entity entity = entityRepository.findOne(Specification.staticMethodForKey(key))`

Later on, this method invokes another method which is private, and in that private method, there is the same initialization, but other field (in a separate method).

`Entity entity = entityRepository.findOne(Specification.staticMethodForKey(key))`

In the `Entity` class there is also an attached `EntityListener`, which is responsible for encoding and decoding the body of the `Entity`. It has two methods, one of them that encodes the body has `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations and the second one, that decodes the body has `@PostLoad` annotation.

When the application encounters first `.findOne()` method, it correctly finds the entity and triggers the method annotated with `@PostLoad` which correctly decodes the `body` of the `Entity`. No other action is performed on it. Later on, when it encounters the second `.findOne()` in the **separate, private method**, Hibernate seems to invoke the flush that triggers the method annotated with `@PreUpdate`, which encodes the `body` of the `Entity`, and actually uses it as the second initialized field. It acts as if it is the thing he found in the repository, thus the `body` of the second `Entity entity` in the private method is actually encoded and used later on in the code, which is wrong, as it should be decoded.

Can someone explain it to me why and how does this happen?

Comment: Are you absolurely sure there's nothing that might trigger commit between the two `find`s?

Comment: Absolutely nothing that might trigger the commit. The only actions performed on these two fields are `.findOne()` and then the `EntityListener` performs the decode/encode, but it should not trigger commit or update.

Comment: Post the offending code where the problem is reproducible. Without the code, this is just a debugging problem that only you can solve.